# Are there overwhelmingly more finite posets than finite groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, posets

A function $f:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ overwhelms $g:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ if for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ the inequality $f(n)\leq g(n+k)$ holds only for finitely many $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$.

For example $n\to n^2$ overwhelms $n\to n$.

Does the number of non-isomorphic posets of cardinality $n$ overwhelm the number of non-isomorphic groups of cardinality $n$?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you give no evidence that it’s research level. Partial information about these functions is not hard to come by.

Comment: In your deleted question today (where you initially compared groups vs topologies), I wrote the following comment, which seems still relevant here: Is there a reason to compare these two seemingly unrelated numbers? the second is highly sensitive to the prime decomposition of $n$ (high for powers of $2$, $=1$ for primes), the first increases with $n$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question: see [@YCor's comment above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391708/is-there-overwhelmingly-more-finite-posets-than-finite-groups#comment999042_391708) and [@‍Wojowu's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391712/are-there-overwhelmingly-more-finite-monoids-than-finite-spaces#comment999047_391712) on your very similar question.  Especially notice that these questions were asked at nearly the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On one hand, the number of groups of order $n$ is at most $2^{O((\log n)^3)}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/422232/127263)). On the other hand, by considering posets which are disjoint unions of total orders, the number of posets of order $n$ is at least equal to the number $p(n)$ of partitions of $n$. Since $p(n)\gg 2^{\sqrt{n}}$, we get the desired result.

Comment: @firn You're right, I missed the $n$ in the base of the exponential.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but the number of posets of order $n$ is $2^{\frac{n^2}{4}+o(n^2)}$.

Comment: @RichardStanley Thanks for the comment! Is that number for posets up to isomorphism or for a labelled set of elements?

Comment: Either way, since $\log n! = o(\log 2^{n^2/4})$.