# Are there overwhelmingly more finite monoids than finite spaces?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, semigroups-and-monoids

A function $f:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ overwhelms $g:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ if for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ the inequality $f(n)\leq g(n+k)$ holds only for finitely many $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$.

Does the number of non-isomorphic monoids of cardinality $n$ overwhelm the number of non-homeomorphic topological spaces of cardinality $n$?

The best upper bound on the number of non-homeomorphic topological spaces of cardinality $n$ I can think of is $$2^{2^{n}-2}-(2^{n}-2)+(n-1)=2^{2^{n}-2}-2^n+n+1.$$To prove that list all the collections of subsets including the empty set and the whole set and then note that the topologies with 3 open sets are determined by the cardinality of the non-trivial open set.

Comment: Are you just going to ask a separate question like that for each pair of sequences out there?

Comment: @Wojowu for many sequences I imagine it's easy to answer so I won't be asking for those

Comment: For this one it's also easy to answer, if you bother looking up some bounds for both.

Comment: Wojowu refers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391708/ and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391691/ (deleted by OP), both asked today by OP.

Comment: In addition, it would be useful to share — what makes you believe the question is particularly relevant? — what are your thoughts on the question?...

Comment: A finite topology is determined by the specialization quasiorder ($x\leq y$ if $x\in\overline{\{y\}}$) it determines.

Comment: You are asking to compare preorders to semigroups.  The exact number of semigroups is not known but speculated.  I guess preorders might be known.  I would guess semigroups overwhelm spaces let me just mention that given any space on n elements  you can build a semigroup on n^2+1 elements by putting S to be all pars (x,y) with x at most y in the specialization order and also with a zero and the nonzero products are (x,y)(y,z)=(x,z)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as @Wojowu mentions, it's not really appropriate to ask many variants on the same question, even if you don't ask all of them, without some indication of why the particular variants you choose are the interesting ones. It's easy to generate lots of hard-to-answer questions, but just being a repository for questions that could be generated algorithmically isn't what MO is about.

Comment: It looks like if your upper bound on spaces is close to the truth spaces overwhelm semigroups

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg It is not close to the truth though, as can be deduced from my prior comment.

Comment: @wojowu which  comment.  Is the asymptotics of quasi orders known

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg No, but an upper bound on the order of $2^{n^2}$ is immediate.

Comment: @wojowu, of course we can count binary relations

Answer (score 2):

An asymptotic lower bound for the number of semigroups of order $n$ according to [Kleitman, Rothschild, and Spencer - The number of semigroups of order $n$](https://doi.org/10.2307/2041879), which is believed to be close to the real thing is $$\frac{\binom{n}{t}t^{1+(n-t)^2}(1+o(1))}{n!}$$ where $t\sim n/(2\ln n)$.  See the paper for exact details and provisos.  This seems to me to overwhelm the upper bound for the number of topologies given by @wojowu of $2^{n^2-n}/n!$ counting unlabeled reflexive binary relations.

Note I gave semigroups but the number of monoids of order $n$ is bigger than the number of semigroups of order $n-1$ and so the answer with monoids is the same.

Comment: Your thing is less than $n^{n^2}$ which is less than $2^{2^{n}}$ (which is basically the upper bound for topological spaces). I don't think it overwhelms.

Comment: @firn, are you sure about that? For n=8 the deleted post had more semigroups than spaces

Comment: I meant asymptotically.